# Adding a line break in a built in slider

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

My client asked me if I could add a simple line break to his slider caption. The website is docksteaderlending.ca. (basically, separate the two sentences in the subheading)

I've exhausted all my tricks and Googled extensively and I can't seem to do it! It's driving me insane.

I have basic html and css knowledge, but am no expert.

Basically the theme is winsome, and it has a built in slider. The slider takes the heading and the subheading from a page, and uses the featured image as the background.

I've tried editing the html of the page. I've tried editing the css. I looked at the slider files, but I have no clue how to do anything php related so...

I'm hoping anyone can help! Thanks in advance

Comment: Where ever you set the subheading, can you manually ad a `<br>` where you want the line break? Or does it just print "<br>" instead of the linebreak?

Comment: Not clear what text you are referring to. The inner HTML of the div with `class='slider-meta'`? Seems like just adding an HTML line break `<br/>` would do it.

Comment: unfortunately <br> does nothing when I add it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if it picks up the title of the slider from the heading of the page, then it would be a little tricky to just add a break. If this is the only page you will have with a slider, then you can just edit the template file and enter the slider text manually, thus breaking it into two sentences.

I have debugged your Winsome theme, so you will be able to edit this without a problem. In Wordpress admin go to "Customize > Editor" and on the right side find the "slider.php" file under "template parts".

On the lines 33 and 37 you will find the following lines:

```
33    <h3><?php echo esc_attr( $slide['title'] ); ?></h3>

37    <div class="slider-meta"><?php echo esc_attr( $slide['excerpt'] ); ?></div>
```

As you can see, line 33 uses the title of the page to show it in the heading of the slider, and line 37 uses the excerpt in the subheading of the slider.

You can edit this in your own taste like this:

```
33    <h3>This is some random text<br>I want to break in two lines</h3>

37    <div class="slider-meta">I will break<br>this text too.</div>
```

Save the file and this should work. Of course, as said, this will only work if you will have a slider on this page only, as I can see you made a landing page without any subpages. If you will plan to use this slider in other pages as well, then there will be more tweaks needed.

Also, not really neccesary for this to work, but try using [a child theme](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/how-to-create-wordpress-child-theme/) for tweaks such as this. Child themes preserve your edits to files such as the one above when you update the theme. Because if you are not working in a child theme and you decide to update your theme then this customized lines will be overwritten.

Comment: Hey this seemed like it would work but unfortunately it didn't. This is what the code looks like now `<div class="caption">
      <?php if( !empty( $slide['title'] )){ ?>
                   <h3><?php echo esc_attr( $slide['title'] ); ?></h3>
                  <?php } ?>

                  <?php if( !empty( $slide['excerpt'] )){ ?>
                   <div class="slider-meta">We specialize in home equity financing from $10,000 to $1,000,000.<br>Access your home equity to: Consolidate Debts, Start or build your business, renovate your home, and more</div>
                  <?php } ?>`

Comment: Also I'm using a child theme

Comment: You can't have one code next to another. Instead of `<div class="slider-meta"><?php echo esc_attr( $slide['excerpt'] ); ?></div>` enter `<div class="slider-meta">We specialize in home equity financing from $10,000 to $1,000,000.<br>Access your home equity to: Consolidate Debts, Start or build your business, renovate your home, and more</div>`.

Comment: Hey I replaced that with your suggestion. it looks like this `<?php if( !empty( $slide['excerpt'] )){ ?>
                   <div class="slider-meta">We specialize in home equity financing from $10,000 to $1,000,000.<br>Access your home equity to: Consolidate Debts, Start or build your business, renovate your home, and more</div>
                  <?php } ?>`

Comment: Do i need to get rid of this > `<?php if( !empty( $slide['excerpt'] )){ ?>`

Comment: I intentionally put a type in the copy, and it seems like the slider is still taking the information directly from the "slider page", not the code I replaced

Comment: Please read the comment. I have said that that INSTEAD of the first code. You have to get rid of the `<?php if( !empty( $slide['excerpt'] )){ ?>` part and enter yours only.